# Is there a meta regular expression language or class?

Tags: c++, regex

I found out that there are differences between the declared controls in the header and dfm files caused probably by copy and paste of formulars.

Perhaps these corrupt fiels are responsible for debugging crashes with CPP Builder XE7!

Therefor I would like check all headers and dfm files regarding integrity.

The first step is to parse the header by this pattern:

```
<TEXT> <Whitspaces> "*" <TEXT> <Whitespaces> ";"
```

First text is the classname, second is the variablename in the header.

Is there a class with meta regular expressions where I can simple write what am I seeking for like the above given pattern?

```
<word> <white> * <word> <white> ;
```

I do not want to use the common regular expressions as this, confusing me every time:

```
 std::string url = "classname * varname  ;";
  boost::regex exp("^w+[ ] etc.");
  boost::smatch match;
  if (boost::regex_search(url, match, exp))
       std::cout << std::string(match[1].first, match[1].second).c_str();
```

Comment: I never used it actually, but may be `boost::spirit` goes into the direction you want.

Comment: I will just point that I still find usual regex syntax quite user-friendly. `\S+\s+\*\S+\s+;` is your pattern. You can use POSIX character classes that are quite verbose: `[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+\*[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+;`. In C++, raw string literals help avoid [backslash hell](https://tudorbarbu.ninja/backslash-hell/).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Boost Xpressive](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/xpressive/):

> Regular expressions that can be written as strings or as expression templates, and which can refer to each other and themselves recursively with the power of context-free grammars.

I've used them extensively and found they work well for searches like (from the user's guild):

```
sregex group, factor, term, expression;

group       = '(' >> by_ref(expression) >> ')';
factor      = +_d | group;
term        = factor >> *(('*' >> factor) | ('/' >> factor));
expression  = term >> *(('+' >> term) | ('-' >> term));
```

Comment: wow, realy boosting... ^^ installing now the bundle and going to test it. thank's a lot friends

Comment: It looks like a totally new language, I believe regular expression syntax is much easier to understand :)

Comment: @stribizhev look at the documentation, you can use normal regexes as well.

Comment: Yes, good. If you ask me, `[[:alpha:]]+`,  `[[:digit:]]+`, `[[:space:]]+` POSIX character classes are very self-illustrative for me.

Comment: C++ is C++. It seems to be a new language, but the trick is : operator overloadings. But unfortunatelly I have a lot of troubles to get this version of boost compiled with XE7 :(

Comment: Xpressive was first released in boost version 1.34.0, so maybe you already have it,.  Or you could try another version from 1.34.0 to 1.60.0.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little bit upset today with my IDE. None of your tips worked unfortunately. So, I had to took again the full responsibility and wrote my own piece of code to find my inner peace again. ^^ I hope that other programmers fighting with regular expressions find this code usefull. It's a bit durty but at least : it works!

HEADER

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class TReggae {
public:
  TReggae();
  TReggae& white  (void);
  TReggae& word   (string& strVar);
  TReggae& text   (string strVar);

public:
 int      iPos;
 string   str;
 bool     boFound;
};
```

IMPLEMENTATION

```
TReggae::TReggae() {
  iPos = 0;
  str  = "";
  boFound = false;
  }

TReggae& TReggae::white (void) {

  for (;iPos < str.length(); iPos++)
    if (!isspace(str[iPos]))
      break;

  boFound = true;

  return *this;
}

TReggae& TReggae::word (string& strVar) {

  strVar = "";
  for (;iPos < str.length(); iPos++) {
    if (!isalnum(str[iPos]))
      break;

    strVar += str[iPos];
    boFound = true;
    }

  if (strVar.length() == 0)
    throw -1;

  return *this;
}

TReggae& TReggae::text (string strVar) {

  if (strVar.length() == 0)    // assert
    throw -2;

  for (int i=0;i<strVar.length(); i++) {
    int iPosTmp = iPos + i;
    if (iPosTmp > str.length())
      throw -3;

    if (strVar[i] != str[iPosTmp])
      throw -4;
    }

  iPos += strVar.length();
  boFound = true;

  return *this;
}
```

TEST

```
void __fastcall TForm3::cxButton1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
  string  strClassName,
          strVarName;

  TReggae Reggea;
  Reggea.str = "class TMyClass { "
               "public: "
               "  TClassName1 * ptrVarName1; "
               "  TClassName2 * ptrVarName2 ;"
               "};";

  for (int i=0;i<Reggea.str.length();i++) {
    try {
      Reggea.iPos = i;

      Reggea.white ()
            .word  (strClassName)
            .white ()
            .text  ("*")
            .white ()
            .word  (strVarName)
            .white ()
            .text  (";");

      wostringstream os;
      if (Reggea.boFound) {
        os << "Found: "
           << Reggea.iPos << " "
           << strClassName.c_str() << " "
           << strVarName.c_str();
        cxMemo1->Lines->Add(os.str().c_str());

        i = Reggea.iPos;
        }
      }
    catch(...) {
      // cxMemo1->Lines->Add("Exception: No match!");
      }
    }
```

OUTPUT

```
Found: 53 TClassName1 ptrVarName1
Found: 83 TClassName2 ptrVarName2
```